# Jenkins build passes when ssh deploy fails

Tags: deployment, ssh, jenkins, continuous-deployment, automated-tests

I'm using a here tag in a Jenkins build step to send my deploy commands over ssh, and unfortunately the build is passing even when the commands inside the here tag don't finish successfully:

`ssh user@host <<EOF
  cd /path/to/app
  git pull
  bower install
  npm install
  grunt build
  cp -r /path/to/app/dist/* /path/to/dist/
  forever restartall
  exit
EOF`

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not catching any error codes inside your "here document".
Last command is `exit` and without an exit code, it will default to `0` which is success.
Since the last command of your `ssh` is a success, the whole command is treated as success, and build is a success.

Easiest way to fix that: chain all commands with `&&` like so:
`cd /path/to/app && git pull && bower install && npm install && grunt build && cp -r /path/to/app/dist/* /path/to/dist/ && forever restartall && exit`

Best way to fix that: write a proper shell script, **with error handling**, and execute that. If you are too lazy to error handle every line, you can start the script with `set -e` which will fail the shell script on any individual error

**Edit:**

```
#!/bin/bash
appPath="/path/to/app"
distPath"/path/to/dist"

echo "My great deployment script"
echo "Deploying ${appPath} to ${distPath}

if [[ ! -w "${appPath}" ]]; then
    echo "${appPath} is not writable, quitting"
    exit 1
else
    cd ${appPath} && git pull || { echo "Failed on 'git pull'"; exit 2; }
    bower install || { echo "Failed on 'bower install'"; exit 3; }
    npm install || { echo "Failed on 'npm install'"; exit 4; }
    grunt build || { echo "Failed on 'grunt build'"; exit 5; }

    if [[ -w "${distPath}" ]]; then
        cp -r ${appPath}/dist/* ${distPath}/ || { echo "Failed on 'copy'"; exit 1 }        
        forever restartall || { echo "Failed on 'forever restartall'"; exit 6 }

        echo "Deployment successful"
        exit 0 
   fi
fi
```

You then execute it with: `ssh user@host 'bash -s' < myfile.sh` (if the file is local)
Or if you place the file remotely, then just: `ssh user@host '/path/to/remote/myfile.sh'`

Comment: Can you elaborate on "write a property shell script, with error handline"? I'd love to do it the right way, but I'm really at the edge of my expertise here! :]